# HTTPS or SSH for server-server communication

Tags: apache, http, ssh, php

I have two servers. I wish to send some data ( was doing it with HTTP GET till now ) to a php file residing on the server and get some output from it.

Of late, I saw the requests per second went up to 50 and Apache served HTTP 500 error for some of those. This server has 512 MB RAM and the script, in php-cli mode, usually eats up around 10 MB of memory.

I wish, if it were to reduce the load on server, to use SSH instead of HTTPS. Will it reduce the memory usage on this server (minus what the script itself needs)? Or will too many SSH connections still cause hindrance?

Note - I do not have HTTPS setup right now. But planning to switch over to it. And just then, this issue cropped up.

Comment: Why are you assuming HTTPS is the issue causing the 500 errors?

Comment: @ceejayoz I wasn't clear. Please check the note in updated question.

Comment: HTTPS has nothing to do with SSH, other than the fact that they both utilize some form of encryption. This question makes no sense.

Comment: @Chris I think you misinterpret it. Check the 2nd and 3rd paragraph again. If I don't use Apache, which has its own memory usage, but use SSH, for communication, would it consume less memory?

Comment: @Chris - I don't think that the OP is making the assumption that they are related, other than the fact you state. The OP is trying to find a more efficient way of sending data one server to another server using encryption.

Comment: Neither of them are going to reduce the load on the server. I don't know if either is going to add significantly to the load either, but if you're having memory issues without either, then I recommend a RAM upgrade.

Comment: OK, so if you used SSH without HTTP, how would you get the data from one machine to the other? SCP?  Would there be 50 of those per second?  Or would you do them in batches?

Comment: @JasonDean I'd setup key-auth for a new user and then do `ssh user@server '/var/script.php param1 param2 param3'`

Comment: If anything, using ssh will only increase memory usage. You've already got Apache running, so that cost is already paid. Then you have to add in a shell + ssh to the Apache overhead.

Answer (score 0):

SSH will not speed up your program. What you can do, is to create your own server on the destination server (which will receive data). The web server do much more than just receive data, like interpret HTTP headers and route your requests to files. Your own  server can do the same job in a much lighter way.

http://br.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php has an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use normal HTTP, but encrypt the data sent.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the data you're wanting to transfer?  Depending on the size SSH (in particular, SFTP) might very well be better.  I say that because...  well, when was the last time you tried to upload a 10MB file via a webpage and succeeded?  Uploading small files works for HTTP but, at the end of the day, it's not a file transfer protocol.

My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  Upload a file via SFTP and then run a PHP script on that file via SSH.